# How to get a vector from multiple columns of multiple files

Tags: r, vector

**So I have**:

1) many csv files of 4 columns

2) *file_storage_names* - a character vector of filenames which I need to open, read and write all the info from these files into a list

3) *data_storage* - a list into which I do things in (2)

**I need**:

a vector *clm* which is made up of all second columns from all the files in the data_storage

**What I do:**

```
data_storage<-list()
clm<-data.frame()


for (i in 1:length(file_storage_names))
{
  data_storage[[i]] <-read.csv(file_storage_names[i])
  clm<-c(data_storage[[i]][[2]])
}
```

My concern: a) Am I doing it right? b) Do I get in *clm* one long vector or a vector of vectors?

Comment: Have you tried it and looked at clm? Try it on 2 instead of all and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing at least some of it right. The loop and the assignment of dataframes into a list is a pretty standard way of reading in a lot of files. I assume you need to save the file data for later; otherwise you wouldn't need to build the list.

`clm <- c(data_storage[[i]][[2]])` does not look right. You're getting the second column of the ith data frame and assigning it to clm. But you overwrite clm each time you pas through the loop. What I think you want is

```
clm <- c(clm, data_storage[[i]][[2]])
```

and before executing the loop initialize clm with

```
clm <- NULL
```

(assuming you want clm to be a vector)
this will give you the results as one long vector (there are not vectors of vectors in R, as you can verify by typing e.g. `c(1, 2, c(3, 4))` at the command prompt.

Or maybe you meant to use `clm[[i]] <- c(data_storage[[i]][[2]])` and collect the data as a list or a dataframe.